# crypt.crypt one-liner works differently as script

Tags: python

I am new to `python` would like to expand the following one-liner to a short script to generate `SHA512` hash that I can use as Linux shadow password.

```
python -c "import crypt,random,string; \
           print crypt.crypt(raw_input('clear-text password: '), '\$6\$' \
           + ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) \
           for _ in range(16)]))"
```

it works fine to print out the hash for example

```
$6$oGLGsdsZpbbjUobu$lxAbyUYV17B5JEgIjAghvL8osZrFUccXkQ.RPW0AE0xbyKdhA.0WE3UWiwVI/0O0lXcaQ3jmIEFXjp5a6JajX1
```

but when I just simple re-write it as following

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import crypt
import random
import string

print crypt.crypt(raw_input('clear-text password: '), '\$6\$'   \
 + ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) \
 for _ in range(16)]))
```

It prints out something does not look like a correct hash.

```
./shadow.py
clear-text password: dir
\$c0UU5dohpjE
```

The one-liner works fine but I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do such a big one liner?

Comment: Why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the one-liner, don't forget that bash is also looking at the script. It takes the `\$` out and translates them to a literal `$`. For some reason this chokes `crypt.crypt`.

I ran

```
>>> crypt.crypt('any string', '\$6\$' + 'abc')
'\\$d5GL183q0Yo'
```

against

```
>>> crypt.crypt('any string', '$6$' + 'abc')
'$6$abc$h7OB.KW3LchliR... (truncated)'
```

in a python interpreter.

Looking at `help(crypt.crypt)` gives me a clue:

> `crypt(word, salt) -> string`
>
> word will usually be a user's password. salt is a 2-character string
>           which will be used to select one of 4096 variations of DES. The characters
>           in salt must be either ".", "/", or an alphanumeric character. Returns
>           the hashed password as a string, which will be composed of characters from
>           the same alphabet as the salt.

It looks like you're using some undocumented feature of `crypt.crypt` which allows you to add characters?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

That first example is *not* the output of the code you gave.  Run it again.

(I am curious why the "\$" prints out for me in the script-file example, but not the inline example.)

**EDIT**: the first two characters of the salt -- in this case backslash and dollar-sign -- are used as the actual salt.   [The rest of the salt are used as the "alphabet" to use in displaying the hash](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html).

I think you think that `\$\6` somehow evaluates out to `$6` in Python.  Nope.

The answer to my question, about why it prints out in the script-file example is that `\$\6` evaluates out to `$6` *in the shell*, before Python ever sees it.

Huh, I wonder if you *don't* put it there, the shell will try to resolve it into the sixth argument.  Why don't you use `chr(36)` instead?

Comment: the one-liner will produce different output each time because it generates a random 16 digit salt.

Comment: Actually, the OP omitted the part where `raw_input` displays the prompt and gets an input from the console, but the output _is_ a hash that looks like what they displayed. And the script version also gives a static mapping of `dir` to `\$c0UU5dohpjE` when run on my end.

Comment: Yes, so for something reason crypt.crypt did not take `'\$6\$'` part ? I am just trying to have a simple script to generate `SHA512` hash I can use for Linux shadow password.

Comment: What do you mean by has nothing to do with pythong ? I figured it out, I do need to escap `$` in one-line but I don't need to escape it in a script. once I remove `\\` in script, it worked ok.

Comment: Malvolio: the shell is involved, but it's not `$6`. It adds a literal `$6$` in front of the string which works as intended. But without this shell replacement, something happens to `crypt.crypt`.